# Why does rsync skip a sub-folder named "core"?

Tags: macos, command-line, rsync

I'm using the following command to synch files from one folder to another on my local OSX system:

`rsync -avC ./src ~/Sites`

Inside of `./src` there are several sub-folders:

- `./src/assets`
- `./src/core`
- `./src/css`
- `./src/js`

All folders and content are copied as expected, except for `./src/core`.  Renaming the folder resolves the problem, but isn't an option.  For example, named as `./src/core2` and it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does that because you asked it to.  Specifically, you asked with `-C` that it "ignore things like CVS does".

That includes various junk like [core dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) that are not really interesting at the far side of the link.  Except it does that by name rather than "type and name", so your directory gets caught in the mix.

From `rsync(1)`, the list of what it excludes:

```
RCS  SCCS CVS CVS.adm RCSLOG cvslog.* tags TAGS .make.state .nse_depinfo *~ #*
.#* ,* _$* *$ *.old *.bak *.BAK *.orig *.rej .del-* *.a *.olb *.o  *.obj  *.so
*.exe *.Z *.elc *.ln core .svn/ .git/ .hg/ .bzr/
```

To ignore files and folders from CVS and include the "core" folder, explicitly include "core" like so:

```
rsync -avC --include "core" ./src ~/Sites
```

Comment: Ah, I need it to ignore .svn stuff, but not a folder named "core"  Overlooked core in that list.  Thank you.

Comment: Can I do both?  First, exclude all that, but then include just my "core"

Comment: I think an explicit include will override the exclude.  Give it a shot.

Comment: Yes, the solution: rsync -avC --include "core" ./src ~/Sites

Comment: Also, rsync respects the ignore list in `.cvsignore`.